# Solving SharePoint Server 2010 - 503. The service is unavailable, After installation

Tags: service, sharepoint-2010, http-status-code-503

Installed:
SharePoint Server 2010 for Internet Enterprise Beta (x64)
On:
Windows Server 2008 Standard (x64) on 64 bit hardware

Attempts to access the Central Administration console led to IIS returning 503. The service is unavailable

And this error was found in the Application log

> The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a x86 processor architecture.

After much ado, the solution turned out to be:

1) Ensure that the enable32BitAppOnWin64 seeting for the "SharePoint Central Administration" app pool is set to False, and the same for the "SharePoint Web Services Root" app pool

2) Edit applicationHost.config:

Change:

```
  <globalModules>
 ...
 ...
 <add name="SharePoint14Module" image="C:\Program Files\Common
 Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
 Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll"
 preCondition="appPoolName=SharePoint
 Central Administration v4" />
 </globalModules>
```

To:

```
    <add name="SharePoint14Module" image="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
 Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll" preCondition=
"appPoolName=SharePoint Central Administration v4,bitness64" />
```

I hope this helps somebody :-)

**bitness64** being the magic word here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) Ensure that the enable32BitAppOnWin64 setting for the "SharePoint Central Administration" app pool is set to False, and the same for the "SharePoint Web Services Root" app pool

2) Edit applicationHost.config:

**bitness64** being the magic word here

Comment: I only needed to do step 1.

Answer (score 36):

I got a 503 error because the **Application Pools weren't started** in IIS for some reason.

Comment: If the error is still occurring after starting the app pools, double check that they are still running. They may have been stopped due to another error.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Beytan Kurt.

I had 503 thrown for both the Central Admin site as well as the SharePoint landing page. In both cases the Passwords were expired.

After resetting the password in the AD, and refreshing the Identity, CA worked but the SharePoint landing page threw a 500 error.

It turned out that the .Net Framework Version was set to V4.0. I changed it to V2.0 and it worked.

Remember after each change you need to recycle the appropriate app pool.

Answer (score 7):

Can You Please try this :
 Check the web site properties in IIS.
 Under home directory tab, check the application pool value 
 Verify that all SharePoint services are started.
If the application is not started do the following:
I think this error might occur because of changing the service account password. 
    You may need to change the new password to application pool
    1)Click the stopped application pool 
    2)click advanced settings 
    3)Identity ->click the user to retype the user 
    4)  Application Pool Identity dialog 
    5)click set -> manually type the user name and password. 
    Then restart the server.

Answer (score 4):

It can also happen if your password policy or something else have changed your password in case your appPools are using the the user with changed password.

So, you should update the user password from the advanced settings of your appPool throught "Identity" property.

The reference is [here](http://nassharepoint.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/sharepoint-site-error-service-unavailable-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable/)

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble finding the applicationhost.config file.  It was in c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\ (Server2008) or the c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ (Server2008r2).

After I changed that setting, I also had to change the way IIS loads the aspnet_filter.dll.  Open the IIS Manager, go under "Sites", "SharePoint - 80", in the "IIS" grouping, under the "ISAPI Filters", make sure that all of the "Executable" paths point to ...Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v#.#.####\aspnet_filter.dll.  Some of mine were pointed to the \Framework\ (not 64).

You also need to restart the WWW service to reload the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer posted here solved one problem, but another is that you'll have to change the app pool to use .Net 2.0.

"SharePoint 2010 uses .NET Framework 3.5, not 4.0.   The SharePoint 2010 app pools should be configured as .NET Framework 2.0 using the Integrated Pipeline Mode."

source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/4727f9b4-cc58-4d86-903b-fabed13da0ff

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with a customer and none of the posted resolutions did the trick. I granted the "Log on as a batch job" permission via the Local Security Policy and that finally made the Central Administration web page come up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this. It helped a lot. The one difference in my applicationHost.config was

```
            <add name="SharePoint14Module" image="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll" preCondition="appPoolName=SharePoint Central Administration v4,bitness64;SharePoint - 80" />
```

Note the multiple semicolon seperated entries. This is probably because I have a single box install of SPS.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Web.config of the application ends up in an unconsistent state (duplicate declaration of http handlers, etc)
To check which line in config is causing the error open IIS Manager and try to edit the handler mappings..it will display you the error line if there is such an error in web config.

Strangely such errors do not get logged in Event viewer or ULS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the password was good and "Log on as batch job" alone was not sufficient.

Check that the IIS application pool identity account or group has both the "Log on as Batch Job" permission AND that it can "impersonate a client after authentication".

To change these settings perform the following steps on the web front end server:

- Start>Run type "secpol.msc"

  - Find: Security
    Settings>Local Policies>User Rights assignment
  - Add user or group to
    "Log on as Batch Job"
  - Check group membership of service account (in
    Active Directory) if a particular group is being used for this
    purpose.
  - Find "impersonate a client after authentication" and add the application pool identity
  - Reboot the server

You should be able to access the site!

Answer (score 0):

Read the user and password in Application -> Advance Settings for Cental Admin application will work.